# Why can't I inline an explicit instantiation of a template function with a single non-type parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, inline, header-files

Say I have a non-type template function `f(int)` (parameter `<int dim>`) declared in `template.h` and defined in `template.cpp`. In `template.cpp` I further add one specialization for `dim = 2`, and then I explicitly instantiate the template function for `dim = 1` and `dim = 2`.

The files compile fine, but during the linking process I get an error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "void f<2>(int)", referenced from:
      _main in main-2AW7ED.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

However, if I remove the `inline` keyword from the template specialization (see mark below), the whole thing works as expected. So here comes my question:

**Why does the `inline` not work for the specialized template, when it works for the base template, when everything else compiles and works just fine?**

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "template.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int, char** )
{
  f<1>(456); 
  f<2>(789);
}
```

*template.h*

```
template <int dim> void f(int src);
```

*template.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "template.h"

using namespace std;

template <int dim> inline
void f(int src)
{
  cout << "src = " << src << endl;
  cout << "dim (template) = " << dim << endl;
}

template <> inline // <== if I remove this "inline", everything works as expected
void f<2>(int src)
{
  cout << "src = " << src << endl;
  cout << "dim (fixed) = " << 2 << endl;
}

template void f<1>(int);
template void f<2>(int);
```

P.S.: I used g++ and clang++ with the command `clang++ -o tmpl template.cpp main.cpp` to compile.

Comment: Why have you even got `inline` on the definitions when you don't have it on the declaration in template.h?

Comment: It's an ODR violation, essentially.

Comment: @TonyD From http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/where-to-put-inline-keyword.html and other sources I got the perception that I only need to put it at one location.

Comment: @KerrekSB Could be more specific please? If it is a violation of the one-definition rule, why only for the specialized template?

Comment: @MichaelSchlottke: Well, whether `inline` or not, if *any* other part of your code uses `f<1>` (and excepting `extern template`s, I should concede), then that code will assume a different definiton of `f<1>` from the explicit instantiation in `template.cpp`. That's an ODR violation.

Comment: @MichaelSchlottke: that FAQ link you list is specifically for member functions... you're doing this for a freestanding function.

Answer (score 3):

If the function is declared `inline`, the compiler does *have to* not generate non-inline version unless a pointer to the function is requested or it decides that at some call site it will be better not to inline it (compiler is not required to always inline even if you declare `inline`).

Now to inline a function, the compiler needs to see the function's definition when compiling the call site. But you defined the function in a `.cpp` and are trying to call it from different `.cpp`. So the compiler does *not* see the definition and tries to call the non-inline version. But it wasn't generated, because you told the compiler to inline the function and it didn't see any use where non-inline version would be needed, so it didn't generate it. If you don't declare `inline`, than default is `extern` and non-inline version gets always generated. And you declared explicit instances you want generated, so those will be.

Just as the compiler does not have to inline, it does not have to generate the extern version. I suspect there is some random difference that causes the compiler to generate the non-inline instance in one case and not in the other. In either case if you declare something inline, it must be defined in the header unless you are only actually using it from the one source (e.g. sometimes private methods can be inline and defined in the implementation, because you are only using them in that one file).

Comment: But why does it work for the non-specialized template and not for the specialized template?

Comment: @MichaelSchlottke: I updated the answer; I really think it's imperfection in the compiler logic rather than any rule.

Comment: Hm. I could accept that it's a compiler issue and not something in the language itself if it weren't for the exact same behavior using two different compilers. But I guess that's what I will have to live with then :)